# java jpql query with 2 parameters

Tags: java, jpql

I have a problem with a jpql query with 2 params:

this is the query:

```
public List<OrganizedUe> findByAcademicYear(Date start, Date end)
    {        
        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String startFormat = format1.format(start.getTime());
        String endFormat = format1.format(end.getTime());            
        List<OrganizedUe> list;
        String queryString = 
        "SELECT o FROM OrganizedUe o "
                + "WHERE o.startDate >= :param1 "
                + "AND "
                + "o.endDate <= :param2 "
                + "ORDER BY o.startDate";
        Query q = em.createQuery(queryString);
        q.setParameter("param1", startFormat);
        q.setParameter("param2", endFormat);
        list = q.getResultList();
        return list;
    }
```

If I run this function, I receive a error from the brownser:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to
>   set a value of type class java.lang.String for parameter param1 with
>   expected type of class java.util.Date from query string SELECT o FROM
>   OrganizedUe o WHERE o.startDate >= :param1 AND o.endDate <= :param2
>   ORDER BY o.startDate.

The strange thing, I looked the value in debug mode for startDate and endFormat and the 2 String have a value like YY-MM-DD but according the error I should send a Date?

I did another test where I hardcode the :param1 and :param2 with this format:  '2014-09-15' and in this case my function works.

Have you an idea from what could be the problem?

Thanks

edit:

this is the definition of start and end in my entity OrganisedUe:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "start_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date startDate;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "end_date")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date endDate;
```

Comment: Please show how you defined `startDate` and `endDate` in your entity `OrganizedUe`

Comment: Hi Nicolas, added in the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of transforming to String just use the date variables instead:

```
q.setParameter("param1", start);
q.setParameter("param2", end);
```

If you need start as the first date and end as the second (as the whole day), you can set them at the beginning/end of the day:

```
start.setHour(0);
end.setHour(23);
start.setMinutes(0);
end.setMinutes(59);
// and the same for seconds :)
```

Just to set the time to 0:00:00 on start and 23:59:59 on end.